# Не могу связать Model с View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Доброго времени суток, не получается связать распарсенный объект Data с представлением. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Model

```
public class Data : ViewModelBase

    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool ServerState { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ServerTimeSpan { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Terminal> Terminals { get; set; }


public class Terminal : ViewModelBase

    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public string SerialId { get; set; }
    public string SimNumber { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionTime { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Sensor> Sensors;


public class Sensor : ViewModelBase

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
```

ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase

    public Data Data;
    public DelegateCommand OpenFileCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(obj => OpenFileExecute(), obj => true);
    }

    private async void OpenFileExecute()
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (!dialogResult.HasValue || !dialogResult.Value)
            return;
        var path = openFileDialog.FileName;

        var xmlParser = new XmlParser();
        var data = await xmlParser.ParseFile(path);

        Data = data;
    }
```

View

```
   <Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="Terminals" ItemsSource="{Binding Terminals}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="Sensors" ItemsSource={Binding }/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ServerState}"/>
   </Grid>
```

Команда работает, парсер тоже.
Вопросы:
1) Как предоставить представлению объект Data и его свойства?
2) Как связать элемент Sensors с выбранным значением элемента Terminals в DataGrid?

Очень нужна помощь, есть очень много информации о Binding, но я как новичок очень быстро в ней утонул и не могу найти конкретные вещи, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. `View` отображает `ViewModel`, как я понимаю, а во `ViewModel` нет свойств `Terminals` и `ServerState`. Зато они есть в свойстве `Data`. Поэтому нужно привязываться к свойствам Data.

Кроме того, если вам нужно отобразить `Sensors` для выбранного `Terminal`, нужно завести соответствующее свойство в модели представления `Data`.

ViewModel

```
public class Data : ViewModelBase
{
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool ServerState { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ServerTimeSpan { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Terminal> Terminals { get; set; }
    public Terminal SelectedTerminal { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="Terminals" SelectedItem="{Binding Data.SelectedTerminal}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Terminals}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="Sensors" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.SelectedTerminal.Sensors}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Data.ServerState}"/>
</Grid>
```

Кстати, просмотр Output в VisualStudio очень помогает найти ошибки Binding'а.

Comment: На самый крайний случай, можно добавить: ViewModelBase должна реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged, что, скорее всего так и есть. И в коде представления View нужно DataContext-у присвоить ViewModel. Понятно, что это очевидные вещи, но и на таких я вначале спотыкался.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, сделал по рекомендации @Vlad вывод таков : System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Data' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel' (HashCode=15562413)'. BindingExpression:Path=Data.SelectedTerminal; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=15562413); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='Terminals'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')

Comment: Сделайте `Data` во `ViewModel` свойством.